# Why does setting 'Master' work differently than setting 'PCM'

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, arch-arm

It could be that I am misinterpreting my results, but it seems to me that I am having inconsistencies. I would appreciate a review with commentary.

## As root user

```
amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
```

Observing the following on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Arch Linux ARM:

Using first syntax:

```
amixer sset 'PCM' 50%
```

output

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback -4919 [50%] [-49.19dB] [on]
```

Yet look at alsamixer

[image]

And running other (-- level) syntax

```
amixer set PCM -- 100%
```

output

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback 400 [100%] [4.00dB] [on]
```

and yields this in alsamixer:

[image]

## As user in /home

**Suddenly PCM is not available, just Master.**

```
amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
```

Using first syntax which works (unlike with PCM):

```
amixer sset 'Master' 50%
```

output:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32768 [50%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 32768 [50%] [on]
```

alsamixer output

[image]

And again using other (-- level) syntax which works:

```
amixer set Master -- 100%
```

output:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

And for completeness, here is the output of alsamixer:

[image]

---

## Notes

- A not very thorough/comprehensive answer: [What's the difference between Master and PCM channels in Alsa?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243661/whats-the-difference-between-master-and-pcm-channels-in-alsa)

Answer (score 1):

"root" v. "non-root" name & range of control is due to PulseAudio.  Some cards have like three different controls that mean nothing to humans, Pulse gives you the one control (for each output you can select in Pulse) and tries to optimize which ones it uses for sound quality.  Simplest if you can stick to non-root, Pulseaudio for everything.

I don't know why the `alsamixer` bar in the first scenario is not reflecting the % out of the range `-10239 - 400` as expected.

Comment: Controls are often quantized. An immediate `amixer sget 'PCM'` etc. will also show what value it is quantized to.

Comment: @dirkt but, the dB value shown is the same between the `amixer sset` output and the `alsamixer` display, it is only the graphical indicator which does not appear to match.

Comment: @sourcejedi It would seem that the ALSA mixer graphical indicator does not support negative values i.e. it always begins with 0.